# SQL Int to Date then 1 year ahead?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an int column that stored dates as follows:

```
201101
201102
201103
```

I need to take these int's and convert them something like this:

```
01/2011
02/2011
03/2011
```

But then in that same column I need to add a year to that date so I want the following column to correspond to the existing

```
201101 = 01/2011 - 12/2011
201102 = 02/2011 - 01/2012
201103 = 03/2011 - 02/2012
```

I did that following so far to make it into a date string:

```
RIGHT(RTRIM([x].[Work_Month]),2) + '/' + LEFT([x].[Work_Month],4) AS PeriodDisplay
```

I just dont know how I would add a year to that then?

Thanks

Comment: You could just add 100 to `work_month` before all the formatting..

Comment: How would I get the 11 month span though? as if I do this it it 01/2011 - 01/2012 when I want 01/2011 - 12/2011 you knwo what I mean?

Comment: Ah, I see - not that simple then.

Comment: would it just be add 99 then?

Comment: nope that doesnt work. nevermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATEADD(yyyy,1,convert(date,RIGHT(RTRIM([x].[Work_Month]),2) + '/01/' + LEFT([x].[Work_Month],4) ))
```

Changes I made:

- added in the /01/ where it was / - in order to set it to be the first of the month, otherwise you can't parse it as a date
- surrounded it in a `convert(date)` function to convert it to be a date type. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)
- surrounded that in a `dateadd` function to add one year. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

If you actually want the column to contain BOTH dates (so the string would be literally 03/2011 - 02/2012) then just take off the dateadd from the first one.  And if you don't want the days, then you could use substring to strip them out. This really is a front-end thing though: SQL Server isn't the ideal tool for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

My advise would be to make them into dates, sort the logic, the convert them to strings.

As opposed to trying to do it all as strings.

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(
    MONTH,
    (work_month % 100) - 1),
    DATEADD(
      YEAR,
      (work_month / 100) - 2001,
      '2000-Jan-01'
    )
  )                           AS "Start",
  DATEADD(
    MONTH,
    (work_month % 100) - 1),
    DATEADD(
      YEAR,
      (work_month / 100) - 2000,
      '2000-Jan-01'
    )
  ) - 1                       AS "End",
FROM
  myTable
```

(Messing with strings is much slower than messing with dates and integers.  So this code may look a little longer, but over any significant number of records you may see a noticable performance difference.)

Answer (score 1):

Get the end month ready in the same format as the start month, then apply the conversion you've already got to both:

```
SELECT
  RIGHT(RTRIM(x.WorkMonth1),2) + '/' + LEFT(x.WorkMonth1,4) + ' - ' +
  RIGHT(RTRIM(x.WorkMonth2),2) + '/' + LEFT(x.WorkMonth2,4) AS PeriodDisplay
FROM (
  SELECT
    WorkMonth1 = Work_Month,
    WorkMonth2 = Work_Month + CASE Work_Month % 100 WHEN 1 THEN 11 ELSE 99 END
  FROM atable
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @T table (wm int)

insert into @T values
(201101),
(201102),
(201103)

select
 right(convert(char(10),dateadd(m,wm%100-1 ,dateadd(yy,wm/100-year(0),0)),103),7) as StartDate,
 right(convert(char(10),dateadd(m,wm%100+10,dateadd(yy,wm/100-year(0),0)),103),7) as EndDate
from @T
```

Result

```
StartDate EndDate
--------- -------
01/2011   12/2011
02/2011   01/2012
03/2011   02/2012
```

Comment: It's different from the OP has requested. The end month should be 11 months from the start one, not exactly one year.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @SampleData Table   ( Value int not null )

Insert @SampleData(Value) Values(201101)
Insert @SampleData(Value) Values(201102)
Insert @SampleData(Value) Values(201103)

Select Cast( Cast(Value As char(6)) + '01' As datetime)
    , DateAdd(mm,11,Cast( Cast(Value As char(6)) + '01' As datetime))
From @SampleData
```

Once you have the values converted to dates, you can use your presentation layer to format the date to appear as `MM/yyyy`.